# What are some online databases that I can search to find the pathways for sythesis of Lignin, Cellulose, GAX?

Tags: plant-physiology, gene-regulation, pathway

I am trying to obtain the pathway information for synthesis of Lignin,GAX and Cellulose in Sorghum. I am quite new to biology and genetics (EE background). I would appreciate it if y'all can provide me with some websites or books where such info maybe available. I have already looked in KEGG. Thank you very much.

Comment: KEGG would be the first choice for pathway data (also/especially for specific species). If KEGG does not give you the data you need, maybe describe what else you need, to give people a better idea in which direction to go.

Answer (score 1):

The other big metabolic database site besides Kegg is [MetaCyc](https://metacyc.org) which certainly responds to searches for lignin and cellulose.

The problem with lignin is that it is a very complex molecule, so in both Kegg and MetaCyc there are a many reactions involved in its synthesis. Cellulose is less complex and I have no idea what GAX is, despite an internet search. If you are so new to biochemical reactions and metabolic pathways that you cannot handle the results of a MetaCyc search on lignin you should easily be able to find articles devoted specifically to [cellulose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellulose) and [lignin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lignin), perhaps using Wikipedia as a start.

Comment: I'd guess it is supposed to be a subscript x, so that @Adi means the various form of Gibberellic Acid: GA3 and etc..